# d7 link two pages within a (draggable) view by image

Tags: media, navigation, views

I'm trying to set up an image gallery that needs to be sortable in D7. So I installed the Views and Draggable-Views modules. Now I have one view with three pages: Gallery, Sort Gallery and Single Image. (Single Image being a view with one larger image and a previous/next link)

All of this works but I can not find a way to link an image in the Gallery-grid to the Single Image view. In the properties of the imagefield I can set up a link, but only to "content" and "file". I need to link that image to that image in my Single Image page. How can I do that?

Any ideas or solutions would be greatly appreciated!!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you must be taking nid as contextual filter in the single image view
if yes then in your grid view you can rewrite the output for the image field and check the output as link field and link path will be the path of your single image view with nid of current node containing image
Please check the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Awesome!! Just took me a few minutes to figure everything out, and turned out exactly as I wanted. Thank you!